# Automatically Paste Data from Latest CSV File in Google Drive Folder to Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a very specific ask for automating a daily data dump to my Google Sheet that I need help with. I am very new to coding so I am not sure exactly where to start, and Googling has not been fruitful so far. I will try to describe my issue with as much details as possible, and happy to provide additional details as needed.

1. Once per day, usually in the AM but not at an exact, specific time, a CSV file is uploaded into a Google Drive Folder called "Daily Pacing Folder"
2. The CSV file always contains the same header column titles, and a variable amount of rows depending on the day
3. The CSV file has a different file name every day
4. The Content of the CSV file are pasted into a Google Sheet named 'Sales Report', with Sheet name 'Raw Data *'. The 'Sales Report' Google Sheet contains a few different Sheets with various functions already in place
5. I cannot overwrite the 'Raw Data *' sheet each day. I would like to take the contents of the latest CSV file, and paste the file into columns E:Y

Ideally what I would like to automate is a script that checks folder 'Daily Pacing Folder', if it sees a new CSV contained in that folder, take CSV contents and paste in columns E:Y into Google Sheet 'Sales Reporting', in sheet 'Raw Data *'.

I would be very grateful if someone could help me out here.
Please let me know if I can provide additional information or clarification, and thank you in advance!

Answer (score -1):

```
function loadCSVintoSpreadsheet() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const resp1 = ui.prompt('Select Sheet Name', 'Enter destination sheet name', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if (resp1.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK && resp1.getResponseText().length > 0) {
    const sh = ss.getSheetByName(resp1.getResponseText());
    //sh.clearContents();
    const resp2 = ui.prompt('CSV FileId', 'Enter file id of csv', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    if (resp2.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK && resp2.getResponseText().length > 0) {
      const file = DriveApp.getFileById(resp2.getResponseText());
      const csv = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
      let csvA = Utilities.parseCsv(csv)
      sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1, 1, csvA.length, csvA[0].length).setValues(csvA);
    }
  }
}
```